# DSP/dsPIC Getting Started

Tags: pic, dsp, digital-filter

I am a last class eee student and I started to study on digital filters. I want to design a 0-150 Hz band pass filter for getting started(I have not determined certain parameters, I want to do something that behaves like 0-150Hz analog bandpass filter. I say it because some experts come and asking always about details and advanced topics. I dont ask that. Just I said my intention, anyway...).(Also I know theory and fundamentals, I started the pyhsically implementation).

I have coded MCUs about 1 years. So I thought that, I could implement a digital filter using a dsPIC easyly. I asked some people to use dsPIC, almost everyone told about that as if it is a s*it. First question is about that, why signallers see the dsPIC as an enemy? Can't I do an digital filter with dsPIC, that behaves like 0-150 hz analog band pass filter?

Secondly, How can I get started with DSPs? For example, for MCU coding, I got a PICKIT2 programmer, downloaded an IDE, and wrote the C codes and the last, I flashed my hex to PIC using that programmer, so all things was that. But I don't know how to start with DSP coding and implementation. What is the requirements? I found some books which were written 15 maybe 20 years ago and DSPs which are in that books are not available yet. I googled also searched from Digi-Key to find a starter kit or any chip to start, and now I am very very confused. If you were me, how did you started with DSPs? (I am a student so low cost kits would be perfect for me)

Lastly, What is the exact discrimination between DSPs and ordinary MCUs? There are always turning the same things about these on the internet. Allmost all of web site writes like copied from wikipedia. The discrimination comes from architecture? For example, can't I use my raspberry PI 3, which has cortex CPU, as a DSP?

I hope some of members don't distribute the topic with details. I tried to ask clearly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I will not comment on the DSP capabilities of an ARM Cortex A (Application) or M (Microcontroller), only focus on how to start with DSPIC. The DSPIC family is well stablished product and excellent for medium DSP applications. I’ve designed several successful products based on it. Also, It is an opportunity to try something different. Microchip has several application notes, mainly in power electronics and control systems. Some features useful for signal processing:

RISC / Harvard;
Barrel Shifter;
Executes 8 operations in 1 instruction;
Fixed point math manages overflow and rounding;
Zero cycle looping;
40-bit accumulators for high-precision results;
Up to 70 MIPS performance;
ADCs with multiple sample and holds;
Peripheral Trigger Generator (PTG) for scheduling complex, high-speed peripheral operations;
Sophisticated PWMs with app specific modes);

Another major advantage when using  Microchip products  is that it provides libraries, for example, complete TCP/IP stack (not a non optimized and minimal lwIP), USB, DSP, motor control, graphical LCD, and so on.  Finally, as Microchip produces a multitude of analog and digital sensors can be easier to integrate with the PIC/DSPIC MCUs. Note: Microchip recently acquired Atmel company.
MikroEletronika  has invested in DSPIC. See the book on:

learn.mikroe.com/ebooks/dspicprogrammingc/

There is a lot of C and assembly code in Microchip web site and Internet. Also, read the DSPIC User's Manual.

It is true that the appearance of 32-bit processors with DSP capacity has diminished interest in dsPICs (16 bits), but do not let yourself be carried away by the "experts." Build your own conclusions. If you are interested, stay on studying about them. Success with your  band-pass filter!

Comment: I will try the dsPICs. Also, I got an DSP starter kit. At the end, I will watch the performance of two platforms.